# Allocating memory and writing (with fread) to string passed as argument to function returning SIGSEGV

Tags: c, string, arguments, malloc, fread

Any clues on what is causing it? This is the function:

```
int readfile(char** s, const char* filename) {
    struct stat st;
    int i;

    if(stat(filename, &st) == -1)
        return 0;

    *s = malloc(st.st_size+1);
    for (i=0; i<st.st_size+1; i++)
        *s[i] = 0;

    FILE* f;
    f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    fread(*s, 1, st.st_size, f);

    return 1;
}
```

And this is how I'm calling it:

```
char* string;
if (!readfile(&string, "filename.ext"))
    fprintf(stderr, "Problem reading file\n");
```

I have no troubles copying what's read by *fread* to a string declared inside the *readfile* function.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `memset (*s, 0, st.st_size+1);` instead of the for() loop would have avoided this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an operator precedence error : http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html

I think what you're trying to do is :

```
for (i=0; i<st.st_size+1; i++)
  (*s)[i] = 0;
```